# Redirecting search engines?

Tags: php

Would this code work to redirect search engines?

```
<?php
function check_if_spider()
{
    $spiders    = array(
                    'Googlebot', 'Yammybot', 'Openbot', 'Yahoo', 'Slurp', 'msnbot',
                    'ia_archiver', 'Lycos', 'Scooter', 'AltaVista', 'Teoma', 'Gigabot',
                    'Googlebot-Mobile'
                );
    foreach ($spiders as $spider)
    {
        if (eregi($spider, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

if (check_if_spider() == 1){
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header ('Location: http://www.site.com');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Some browsers (Konqueror and I think Opera - and possibly Firefox via plugin) let you change the user-agent string, so you could try it yourself to see what happens.

Comment: Not reliably. Whatever you are trying to do, you're going about it the wrong way. Why do you want to try to redirect indexing bots?

Comment: @Wesley - our site is moving to a different domain, but until all of our users have transferred across - we only want to alert the search engines, so our rankings change ahead of time. Thats not fraud mate.

Comment: you dont need to loop it you could use `in_array()`, `check_if_spider() == 1` should be `check_if_spider() === TRUE`

Comment: @Kyle an exception indeed, I felt the need to throw an warning though :).

Comment: You might want to append `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to the redirection target unless you want *all* your old URIs redirected to *one* domain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would. But the function above is pretty non-optimal (it uses deprecated eregi() instead of simple string function strpos()). Also be careful: spider bots don't like situation when you display them content which is different from content for user browsers.

Comment: I suppose they'd know the difference if there were covert spider bots posing as browsers, and then comparing results to the spiders that identify as spiders...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think:

- [ergei](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) is deprecated: From PHP manual:

  This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.
- Your function `check_if_spider()` returns TRUE/FALSE but you're checking for 1 outside, not very intuitive and readable code.
- It is much better to handle search engine bots in [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org) or else via [mod_rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in your .htaccess/config rather than inside PHP code.